# Log database CUD operations and rollback statements on demand

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, logging

My application uses `Hibernate`/`Spring`/`Struts`/`MySql`.

The requirements are:

1. Log the HQL queries w.r.t user SessionId.
2. Revert/rollback statements on demand.

Intention is to quickly log the changes user does to data and also revert instantly if needed. I am not sure about the feasibility of such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The fist, look at [hibernate-envers](http://envers.jboss.org/) project. This project helps you to make changes audit. Its creates audit table for every entity table and fills it automatically when entities has been changed. But the second part of task, I suppose, you can do only manually: in audit tables will be stored all entities changes. Then you can simply revert data in entity to the last version.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are [ACID](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/) and they are durable. Rolling back a committed transaction is not possible, because there might be other transactions already using the state state you changed.

You probably want a [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) architecture, where events are stored in the data base (solving the audit logging requirement too) and the changes are replayed by a [batch processor](http://vladmihalcea.com/scheduled-jobs-best-practices/).

The easiest way to revert an action is by submitting a compensatory event.